# Use Vim to copy lines and paste after another line?

Tags: vim

In Vim I've learned that if I want to move lines x through y after line z I can issue this command where 'm' stands for move:

```
:x,y m z
```

Is it possible to simply copy (or yank) a range of lines and then paste them after a third line?  I've tried substituting 'y' (yank) for 'm' but that doesn't seem to work.  It just yanks the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `copy` or `t`:

- `:x,y copy 3`
- `:x,y t 3`

Where `x,y` is the range of lines to copy.

- Another solution is to hold lines in one of the registers let's say `z` and then put its content after line 3:

`:x,y yank z`

`:3 put z`

---

`:help :t` `:help :copy` `:help :yank` `:help :put`

Comment: That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

`:y 10 y` will yank 10 lines in vim and 
`:p` will paste them

Comment: "y 10 y" doesn't make sense to me.  Also, I'd like to do the yank and paste all on one line while also specifying the line I'd like them pasted after as I illustrated in my move command above.  I'm looking for a one-liner.